# WHERE id='2bar' for INT(11) field returns false positive id=2

Tags: mysql

How to make sure that MySQL does not find false positives when a alphabetic character is appended to a integer value?

Turns out that given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `mytable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

And this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`='2'
```

That works OK and shows a result where `id=2`. But i noticed that a string value of '2abc' in the query also returns the that row: a false positive. I'd rather have the query fail and signal that it could not find that `id` in `mytable`..

This could be circumvented by making sure the value is a valid integer before running the query, but i'd rather keep it string-compatible for future purposes.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89760/prevent-mysql-from-mangling-queries-by-casting-string-to-int and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708253/prevent-mysql-casting-string-to-int-in-where-clause

Comment: This is well documented in the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html check for line `The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'. ` So without explicit type cast it will convert the string to integer and in your case `2abc` becomes 2 and `2=2 => true`, this is called silent conversion `select '2ab'+0; => 2` but  `select 'ab2'+0 => 0`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty if you add your comment as an answer i will accept it so you get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well documented in the doc 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Check for line

> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may
>   convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

So without explicit type cast it will convert the string to integer and in your case 2abc becomes 2 and 2=2 => true, this is called silent conversion

`select '2ab'+0; => 2`

but

`select 'ab2'+0 => 0`